# Abundance data that is hard to fit to GLMM

Tags: statistics

I have abundance data that was collected from video quadrats along a transect line at 3 treatment levels. I also have percent kelp cover for this dataset. My model is as follows:

Abundance ~ Treatment + KelpCover + 1|Transect

The data is overdispersed, and looks like this:

[Treatment abundance boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq01P.png)

[KelpCover abundance graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvIyl.png)

I have tried fitting negative binomial, gaussian, and log distributions with raw data, standardized data, and scaled data. I continue to get cone shaped [residual vs fitted plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A3sC.png) and terrible [predicted vs actual plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuhWb.png) (negative binomial used for this example). The p values and estimates for all the models are similar, just the model fit seems to be bad by visual inspection.

I am at a loss of what to try next. Can anyone suggest why this data doesn't seem to want to be modelled? And possible solutions?